# Vagrant would not provision docker

Tags: docker, vagrant, provisioning

My vagrant configuration does not even start to provision docker and reports no errors at all. Could somebody tell me what's wrong with it? I tried to tear down the machine and bring it up again as well as reloading it with --provision option.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "../..", "/orangebox"

    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.pull_images "kbhit/orangebox-server"
        d.pull_images "kbhit/orangebox-client"
        d.run "kbhit/orangebox-server",
            cmd: "python2.7 /app/runserver.py --mockdata=true",
            args: "-d -v '/orangebox/server:/app' --publish=5000:5000"
        d.run "kbhit/orangebox-client",
            cmd: "npm install && grunt build && grunt serve",
            args: "-d -v '/orangebox/client:/app' --publish=9000:9000"
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't have nested Vagrant.configure("2") just like here... otherwise the second one is ignored.